# Facebook application is not available to all Facebook users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, publishing, iframe-app

I have created an application using iframe / Javascript. I developed the whole application , I tested with my and one of my friend's FB user Id. It worked fine.

Now when I try from a third person's Login but I could not find my application from serach box.

I have already turned off "Sand Box" mode. So that it is available to general users.

Right now it is only availble to me and my test user.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you access the app directly through it's namespace?

i.e http://apps.facebook.com/{appName}

Just because the result isn't returned by search doesn't necessarily mean the app isn't working.